# What code do I need to write a csv file from my raspberry pi to a folder in my local network?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

As of right now, my code will write a csv file with the data I need to the desktop called lights.csv. I would like it to write to a folder on my local network so that I can access it easily from my windows computer. I think this is the best way to see the files written from multiple pi's. This is the code I have right now. I am new to Python, so any help would be appreciated:

```
outputFile = open('lights.csv', 'w')
for i in range(len(button_array)): 
    #Convert the button's time_on variable to a string and append a comma and newline.
    outputFile.write(str(button_array[i].total_time_on) + ',\n')

outputFile.close()
```

All that does is tell me the time certain buttons were pressed, and then write it to the raspberry pis desktop. I would like it to go to a specified folder on my network.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to have the file to be over written each time?  If so why not write the file locally (on the pi) using the standard python [csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) package and then use something like [shutils](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html) to copy the results to the network share?

Comment: I could always go into the network folder and change the name of the file (I was thinking to the date it was written) so that it won't be overwritten. But I'm not familiar with shutils so I don't know exactly how that works.

Comment: If you look at my answer you can click on the link to the shutils documentation.  It is a python package so you import it into your program and use it.  Near the top of the documentation page they go over how to use "shutil.copyfile(src, dst)" which is what you need.